# Display Firebase Data in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a UITableView display data from my firebase database which is in the following structure[image]

I need the first label to display the shop's name and the shop's type. When I print the values from the database, it displays the list of the shops and the type next to it. However, I am finding it difficult to replicate this into the UITableView. Thank you for the help. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase


struct shopStruct {
let shopName: String!
let shopType : String!

}



class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate  {


@IBOutlet weak var homeTableView: UITableView!
var databaseRef: DatabaseReference!
 var shops = [shopStruct]()




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

    databaseRef.child("shops").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let valueDictionary = snapshot.value as? [AnyHashable:String]
        {
            let shopName = valueDictionary["name"]
            let shopType = valueDictionary["type"]

            self.shops.insert(shopStruct(shopName: shopName, shopType: shopType), at: 0)
            self.homeTableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return shops.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    let label1 = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    label1.text = shops[indexPath.row].shopName

    let label2 = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    label2.text = shops[indexPath.row].shopType


    return cell
}

}
```

Comment: what the problem you're facing

Comment: it just doesnt display the name and type in the table

Comment: tried to print shopName in the callback

Comment: if I do that it displays the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.homeTableView.dataSource = self
```

Comment: when i do that it does this libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: sure that the tableView is connected in IB

Comment: It is connected in IB

Comment: you have to register the cell

Comment: I have tried registering the cell but it doesn't work either. However, I tried to cell the label with tag to a random text but it still doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169029/discussion-between-matthew-bird-and-sh-khan).

Answer (score 0):

May be it's not working because you'r reloading the tablebview on secondary thread so could you please replace the code `self.homeTableView.reloadData()` with following code and try?

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.homeTableView.reloadData()
                    }
```